# add to cart has been disabled after installing check delivery netsolutions from magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I have installed Check availability by zip/postal code from magento connect so that it checks product availability using pincode.

reference :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/check-availability-by-zip-postal-code.html

It is working fine but my add to cart button in all my product page is disabled.

I guess **checkdelivery.xml** is conflicting. please guide me how to enable add to cart button.

[image: add to cart not working]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="head">
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/Checkdelivery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addCss" ifconfig="checkdelivery/nsi_general_grp/active" ><stylesheet>css/checkdelivery/style.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
<!--<block type="checkdelivery/checkdelivery" name="checkdelivery.checkdelivery" template="checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml"/>-->
<block type="checkdelivery/checkdelivery" name="checkdelivery.checkdelivery">   
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="checkdelivery/nsi_general_grp/active">  
                      <template>checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml</template>       
                </action>
</block> 
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: I think it might be any conflict of module with your current theme or something. Try changing to default theme(magento default) and check.

Comment: also check for any javascript issues in that page using firebug or something.

Comment: it is default theme itself

Comment: Did you checked for any script issues?? if you are in firefox, click cntl + shift + k to see.

Comment: it is giving: TypeError: $j(...).cycle is not a function....................TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function

Comment: what should i do to remove dese errors

Comment: Sorry its not clear. It would be better if site url posted here.

Comment: im working on localhost,,can u guide me how to debug those errors

Answer (score 0):

you can disable button by below code:

> document.getElementsByClassName("button btn-cart").disabled = true;

Comment: its already disabled after putting this extension, i want to enable it